# O que fazer para ler uma coluna no excel com números muito grandes?

Tags: java-ee, apache-poi

Como fazer para quando ler uma coluna do excel cujo número é muito grande e evitar que o mesmo seja interpretado com estouro?

No Excel a coluna está com o número `26468314801`. Como é um número ele carrega `2.6468314801E10` , procurei a solução e alguns colegas orientaram que transforme a coluna em texto, mas não tenho como controlar o usuário final.

Como faço para que eu consiga carregar corretamente sem este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcelo,

Transforme a celula da seguinte forma: `new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue()))`, ou `utilize DecimalFormat`.